# Windows 10 Chinese (Traditional) language option differences?

Tags: windows-10, language-pack, chinese

When I try to add **Traditional Chinese** language to **Windows 10**, I have 3 choices:

1. Hong Kong SAR
2. Macau
3. Taiwan

What are the differences with these options? How do I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### **What are their differences?**

> ### [Chinese Language Features in Windows 10 & Windows 8](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/windows-8/win8-chinese-intro.htm)
>
> **The "Simplified, China" and "Simplified, Singapore"** regional options include the Microsoft Pinyin phonetic input method, formerly
>   known as SimpleFast until Windows 8.1. The MSPY New Experience input
>   method has been retired, but in Windows 8.1 the popular Wubi
>   stroke-based input method was added. New Experience was my favorite,
>   but in China most users prefer Pinyin input methods that visually
>   separate each syllable. See the list of setup pages below to get
>   started.
>
> **The "Traditional, Taiwan", Hong Kong, and Macau** regional variants include the New Phonetic input method, renamed "Bopomofo" in Windows
>   8.1 even though it will do Zhuyin *and* Pinyin. Also included are Cantonese Phonetic (CPIME, see the next paragraph), Changjie
>   (Cangjie), Quick, Traditional Dayi, and Traditional Array. Although
>   Bopomofo is the default keyboard for Taiwan, and Quick is the default
>   for Hong Kong, these are easily changed. See the links at the bottom
>   of this page for setup instructions.
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/windows-8/win8-chinese-intro.htm)</sub>

---

### **How do I choose one over the other?**

> ### [Chinese Pinyin Setup in Windows 10](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/windows-10/windows-10-pinyin-setup.htm)
>
> Some of you may choose based on which input method you prefer. But
>   **it's often very important to make your choice based on the region you
>   are in or communicate with most** — mainland/Singapore vs.
>   Taiwan/HK/Macau — **to match the
>   [encoding](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/pinyin/encoding.htm) underlying
>   your documents and messages. This helps avoid future technical
>   problems, like unrecoverable scrambled messages full of question
>   marks, "tofu blocks", and other garbage characters.**
>
> To make matters even more confusing, many people in Singapore use the
>   Taiwan or HK locales for Traditional characters, and many in Hong
>   Kong/Macau use the PRC locale for Simplified. And, the Taiwan/HK/Macau
>   settings offer a choice of Big5 or Unicode. It's best to ask people
>   about their settings before sending much, if they know.
>
> The default Chinese "region" choices are mainland China and Hong Kong
>   for most users of an English-language Windows release. Microsoft has
>   put the Traditional character display language pack downloads only in
>   the Hong Kong settings. (Unlike Windows 8 the Taiwan and Macau locales
>   do offer the handwriting feature, and all include speech.)
>
> [image: **enter image description here**]
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/windows-10/windows-10-pinyin-setup.htm)</sub>